# Focus is going to the first field after dropdown in a form - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When i select a value in a dropdown using keyboard and then press tab is focusing the first field in the form.

This is a bug in bootstrap framework i guess.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5p341amh/243/)

```
 http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns
```

[Bootstrap page link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

Comment: In bootstrap the dropdown elements are buttons, which happen to have dropdown functionality. So they behave like buttons and lose focus when they are clicked. you may have to enforce the focus retention yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap the dropdown elements are not `select` elements but are `buttons` which happen to have dropdown functionality. So they behave like buttons and lose focus when they are clicked. you may have to enforce the focus retention yourself.

You can enforce the focus on change of value so that the default bootstrap behaviour is over-ridden

```
$("#dropdownMenu2 button").focus();
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwovd1xv/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regular `<select>` element? The tabbing works now. Also, you should wrap your form in an actual `<form>` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/5p341amh/245/